# android - screen not formatted as expected

Tags: android, android-fragments

I apologize for the vague title, I'm not really sure how this problem would best be identified, and had difficulty finding preexisting questions on this matter.

I want the screen to look like the image on the left, but in practice it's looking like the image on the right.

[image: Desired Image (Left) vs. Current Image (Right)]

The left is the fragment for a drawing toolbar, with placeholder icons for a pencil and eraser shown. It's desired that it always be in the bottom corner of the screen, while the rest of the screen is a drawing field (which is implemented in another fragment). I have a single activity which instantiates both fragments, which is shown on the right. As you can see, the toolbar elements are not in the desired spot. I do not know why this is happening. I know that I can move the toolbar fragment to its desired spot by adding buttons and such to the other fragment, but that would obfuscate the drawing field and so it is not desirable. How do I best deal with this issue?

Below is code for both XML files:

Drawing Toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pencil"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/pencil"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/eraser"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/eraser"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the Instantiating Activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingActivity">

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.chris.drawingtest.DrawingFragment"
        android:id="@+id/Drawing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_drawing"
    />

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.chris.drawingtest.ToolbarFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Toolbar"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_toolbar"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawing fragment has no content currently. The toolbar content does have content. It is directly below the drawing fragment.

Something below nothing ends up being at the very top.

<strike>To fix this, add this line to your XML for the toolbar fragment:</strike>

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Sorry, read this too quickly. `LinearLayout` doesn't provide `layout_alignParentBottom`. Instead, you'll want to use this:

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

Comment: It was layout_gravity rather than gravity that did it for me, but it's working now. I figured as much with the 'something below nothing' concept, but didn't know how to handle it. Thanks again for the help.